# Syntax error while doing join on multiple keys in pig

Tags: apache-pig

Trying to join 2 file content in pig

```
StringFile = load 'String' using PigStorage(',') as (name,branch,div); -- string values
NumFile = load 'num' using PigStorage(',') as (id,m1,m2,m3,m4); -- numeric values
joined = join id by name,(m1,m2) by branch,div by (m3,m4);
store joined into 'joinedfile' using PigStorage(',');
```

But showing

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <file filterjoin.pig, line 4, column 14>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '('
```

> Anju,IT,A --stringFile
>
> 1,5.3,3.6,1.6,0.3 -- numFile

Trying to get output as

```
1,Anju,5.3,3.6,IT,A,1.6,0.3
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

From text book

> You can also join on multiple keys. In all cases you must have the
>   same number of keys, and they must be of the same or compatible types
>   (where compatible means that an implicit cast can be inserted

```
1. It should be same number of keys?

    id by name
    (m1,m2) by branch
    div by (m3,m4)
Is this not possible?

2. while joining, the datatype should be same?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood what `join` does.  It joins two datasets by a common element. So the syntax is:

```
C = join A by a1, B by b1;
```

where a1 and b1 are fields of their respective relations and they also have comment elements.

Example:

```
students = 
1 rob
2 john 
3 fred

gpas =  
1 3.2 
2 3.8 
3 4.0

A = join students by id, gpas by id;

A =  
1 rob 1 3.2 
2 john 2 3.8 
3 fred 3 4.0
```

Comment: +1 Thank you robthewolf. And that field should be common in both bag right? What if I need to join as i mentioned above?

Comment: As it stands there is no straight forward way to do it.  You are trying connect two lines that have no connection.  Unless of course the lists are ordered. For which there is no guarantee.  You would probably have to do it with a UDF if that was the case.  I suggest thinking hard about what you want to do and about what I explained about join and seeing if you can find a way round it.  I would create a third lookup table that could connect the 2 you already have.

Comment: robthewolf if I generate an id for both the files and try to join ,it may work right(including UDF)?

Comment: If you have IDs that match I do not think you will need a UDF as well

Comment: @ robthewolf: How the order changes in tuple?row by row interchage or column by column interchange or both.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking in your last comment.  If it is a new question you should post a new question

Comment: Can we delete or remove the duplicate id created while joining while joing we are getting 2 identical columns. How to remove  that?

Comment: you cannot delete the column, you need to do a foreach and generate all the columns you want (ie dont generate the repeated id column)